# Python : why does existence checking of set() take O(n) in worse case?

Tags: python, time-complexity

According to https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity, `x in s` operation take `O(n)` in worst case.

Since set use hash internally, I think it should be `O(1)` instead of `O(n)`?

Comment: The worst case is that the hash of every single item in the set collides.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, Thanks. One question. If every single item had same hash value, how can `set()` find the item internally??...

Comment: It has to check every item for equality, i.e. falls back to `any(item == x for item in s)`.